# Why <Qtalgorithm> don't have better support for STL algorithms like QtContainers supports STL containers?

Tags: qt, stl

I am working on a Qt c++ project, I have used Qt STL containers like `QVector`, `QList`,
But using `<QtAlgoritm>` has less methods than STL c++ `<algorithm>`'s do.

I am now using `QtContainers` and `QtIteraters` with standerd STL `<algorithm>`'s. Is it the right way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fine and intentional. `QtAlgorithms` does not attempt to duplicate what is already in STL algorithm library and much duplicated stuff has been deprecated in the most recent Qt versions (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html). But beware of the problem of unwanted detachment of Qt containers when using algorithms. Prefer using const iterators or cast the container to const reference before using it in a algorithm to avoid unwanted detachment (i.e. deep copy) or use `std::as_const` or `qAsConst` where possible. The same holds for range `for` loops from C++11. Use a static analyzer like Clazy to indicate such potential problems.

Btw. this video is definitely worth watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZ68dX1-sVc

Here is yet another library which you may find useful https://github.com/KDAB/kdalgorithms